# What is Community Wiki and when should I use it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, community-wiki, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When to mark the ‘community wiki’ checkbox on a new question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/when-to-mark-the-community-wiki-checkbox-on-a-new-question)
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

I have been chastised for marking things "Community Wiki" when they shouldn't be. I thought anything that would help the community would go there, but maybe I'm wrong. Help please!

Thanks!

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea the "possible duplicate of" comments were autogenerated.

Comment: ... or that they disappeared after question closure.

Answer (score 1):

[oh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888)

Comment: That's a proposed FAQ entry; there's actually [an official FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow), too.

Comment: Good answer, though!  :)