# What is Community Wiki for? Can / should checking it be undone in my case?

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

It appears to me that "What is Community Wiki for?" should be a frequently asked question. That is: it was not among SO's faq's. I asked a question that could not have just one answer, but it was of a technical nature. I checked it, I believe  incorrectly, as Community Wiki.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts is the general CW FAQ that'll explain that CW is one-way and irreversible. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/when-to-mark-the-community-wiki-checkbox-on-a-new-question is a proposed FAQ for when CW should be used when asking new questions.

Comment: @Grace Sorry for using your exact links. I swear I looked them up myself!

Comment: Thanks for the schooling. You both found these links, and I didn't.

Answer (score 2):

It is a Frequently Asked Question:

[What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

[When to mark the ‘community wiki’ checkbox on a new question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/when-to-mark-the-community-wiki-checkbox-on-a-new-question)

The FAQ on the top is different that then [Community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/).

Comment: I should have stated that it is not in SO's faq.

Comment: +1 to cancel out someone's downvote