# convert old question to community wiki

Tags: discussion, questions, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)
>   [When to mark the 'community wiki' checkbox on a new question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/when-to-mark-the-community-wiki-checkbox-on-a-new-question)

How can I convert my own old question to community wiki?

I'm not really sure how this can be done. Does a question or an answer have to have meet some kind of standards first in order for it to be able to be converted to a community wiki?

Comment: Flag for moderator attention and choose "Other" option along with the reasoning.

Comment: Most likely it shouldn't be wiki'd but closed...  Lemme peek... Hmm, nope, don't see anything.

Comment: Also, my bad on that one closure... Fixed it to be too localized.  "My development tool is too slow.  How can I speed it up" isn't really a question, btw.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Won't - I was thinking on expanding more on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246797/benefits-of-manual-lookup-over-joining-in-linq and convert it into a community wiki, that's why I wanted to find out if a question should meet some standard to be one. Obviously it does. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: You can't, only a mod can, but more importantly, you probably *shouldn't*.  See the second link as to this is closed as a dupe as to see why.