# Does stack exchange still have a place for community wikis on main site questions?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Given the tight guidelines on questions, and the [reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/55891/234193) that many posts are made into community wikis is that the questions may not be the best fit questions. Meta sites are a little different, as there is the option to have discussion.

Is there really a  point to having the option of turning questions on the main sites into community wikis?

---

**edit** my question didn't ask it very well, it used one example, but it general to me it seems unclear where there place is on the network atm.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Comment: @RobertHarvey can I make this into a feature request to abolish CW from our main sites? It will end the never ending meta requests across [se] with people asking for their Qs to become CWs, I may add, I always answer such posts with a CW (which no one has seemed to notice that bit of humor :)

Comment: Based on Grace's answer, I'd say you'd have more luck if your feature request was targeted at only removing the ability for *questions* to become community wiki and just ignoring the fact that it still would exist for answers. There are valid use cases for CW to be used on answers, as Grace noted. *(See what I did there)* :)

Comment: @jmort253 We already abolished normal user ability to make questions CW. We still need some measure of application (via mods) for when sometimes it can be handy. I'd hate to take away something across the network for what some sites have actually been able to use really well without abuse. Hence the search for a better answer, though.

Comment: @GraceNote ah but then what people do is go to the meta site and post a question asking that their question become a CW.. If there were no CW on main sites, then we would at least finish this continual hamster wheel of *can my Q be a cw...* the subsequent polling and the long time member stating.. *cw bla bla bla*.. if that makes sense

Comment: @Skippy Mods have all the right to just say "no, CW isn't used for that". And they should do that. I imagine answering "Why is my question closed it should be reopened" is no more onerous and in fact is pretty much the same response.

Comment: OK did the brave thing and asked for murder http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209689/can-we-abolish-community-wiki-on-questions-on-main-sites

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been actually doing a lot of thinking on this very subject. It's part of a potential revamp I've been trying to look into.

Fact is we use Community Wiki for *a lot* of things across the network. And in honesty? Very little of it has to do with "not being the best fit". It actually tends to be more often used for things like doing away with credit (like when copying someone else's answer from another post), when combining the contributions of multiple users, or building up information that isn't available at the time of answer from just a single user. Even the "use it for soft questions" portion is not nearly as large as the contingent where it's used for other reasons.

Now, that we use Community Wiki for these things, among several other uses... it may not be the best tool. My plan is to look into what kind of specific solutions we can do for each of the various things we use Community Wiki for currently. It may still be Community Wiki, it may be something else.

I'd say we still have a place for it. Whether it'll stay in the same shape that it does now, though, I'm hoping not.

Comment: yes, that is a good answer, and my question didn't ask it very well, it used one example.. but it general to me it seems unclear where there place is on the network atm

Comment: At the moment, it's going to stay because we don't have better options for what we *do* need parts of its functionality for. It is kludgey but it gets the job done.

Comment: *kludgey* please explain? Is this Klingon?

Comment: @Skippy [Apparently they don't use an e but all the same](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kludgy#English).

Comment: Ah, so it IS a word. albeit a kludgy word lol

Answer (score 2):

Most of the questions that I see where people have asked, "why can't we just turn this into a community wiki post", have generally been questions that hold some marginal benefit to the community yet are so broad that they dilute the site. When community wiki is used to allow broad questions to flourish, it can actually discourage others from asking several, more detailed questions about more specific problems. Since a Stack Exchange site's visits per day metric, and how valuable it is to the world, is determined by the amount of quality content, encouraging folks to ask more detailed questions while also increasing the sheer number of good questions is a win-win for a site's growth and utility.

One example I can think of is the [Common (Project Management) Challenges](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/609/common-pm-challenges) on the Project Management SE site, where a user asked for a list of all of the common challenges faced by project managers. Thing is, every question is inherently about some problem faced in the field of project management, so to try to list them all would be incredibly redundant.

While some users did make well-reasoned arguments as to how such a post could be helpful, allowing such a post could potentially pull the legs out from under the many many more detailed questions that could arise out of instead picking a single challenge and then asking a very detailed question about *that* specific problem. In short, posts where answers contain solutions to problems instead of just lists of problems are more valuable.

Instead of keeping the post opened, we closed it, with the goal of *maybe* using it as a table of contents for linking to real, actual problems that highlighted a common challenge listed in the Common PM Challenges post. We never got as far as to actually ask those questions or compile them into a wiki, but that would seem like one good way to possibly use community wiki, but then again, we have tags for organizing content, so even then [community wiki seems like something that is truly dead](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

In summary, I never use community wiki on the main sites.

Comment: Yes, [so] has such history and [se] has evolved, that I don't see it as having any real purpose on the main sites, I totally agree. btw when I read *common pm challenges* I thought wow a question on politics.. PM here means prime minister, I was wondering why you were using such a boring example! lol But no, proj mangemnt I see the difference :)

Comment: Funny, @Skippy, as I actually thought someone might misconstrue what "PM" was. :)  I edited so that it's a little more clear to others who might think the same.

Comment: hahahahahhaa saw the edit, seriously, I am sure I am one of a rare group of morons who would have read it that way.. I really wish I could +100 on the point of a CW can take the place of many smaller more specific questions